# Simple show/hide jQuery troubles

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Any help on this problem would be appreciated. I have a main navigation like so:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Nav 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nav 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nav 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nav 4</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Somewhere below there is a content div like so:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="block-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block-3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block-4">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The #content div has display:none; set in the stylesheet. As do each of the blocks inside it. When someone clicks a nav item I would like it to show the content container, with only that block the corresponds to it. Nav1 = block-1 etc... When you click another link it hides the other and shows the new selection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a [quick JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/WNNsG/) for you. Using jQuery's `.index()` method, you can get the index of the clicked link, and use that to show the correct div. I've used a class in the following code to show/hide your div. You could replace this with an extra bit of logic to fade each div, for example.

Another point to make is you don't need the `-1`, `-2`, etc postfixes on the divs; `index()` and the `:eq()` selector handles this for you. I've changed your HTML slightly and here is the JS:

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul a").click(function() {
        var index = $(this).parent().index();

        $("div#content").find(".show").removeClass("show");
        $("div#content").find(".block:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("show");
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
 </ul>

<div id="content">
  <div class="block">
    <p>Lorem ipsum 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Lorem ipsum 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Lorem ipsum 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

In response to the comments, here's an update example that will hide every element when the first `li` is clicked. To make it more versatile, you could add a class (say, `hideall`) to the `li` and use `.hasClass("hideall")` inside the `if()` instead of `index == 0`, which checks to see if this is the first `li` in the list. [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/ypZse/), JS below. I've edited the HTML in the Fiddle a little.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul a").click(function() {
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        console.log(index);

        if(index == 0)
        {
            $("div#content > div").removeClass("show");
        }
        else
        {
            index--;
            $("div#content").find(".show").removeClass("show");
            $("div#content").find(".block:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("show");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Jam. (and everyone).

Comment: My only other question - What if the first name item was a "catch all" meaning it hides the #content block every time no matter what. The other items reactivate it and show their block.

Comment: @Fuego Please see my edits. I wouldn't recommend hiding the container; it's extra work to re-show it _and_ the inner `div`, so the new code just hides all inner `div`s, giving you the behaviour you want. The code should hopefully be self explanatory, but don't hesitate to ask if you don't get something.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is jQuery tabs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: I'm sorry, but it really isn't; don't suggest an entire framework for something that can be solved with 8 lines of jQuery and a little CSS.

Answer (score 0):

*First*: do not hide the content DIV. It is unneccessary and only makes the showing/hiding of the block DIVs more complicated.

*Second*: Change the DIVs to this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="block-1 block">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block-2 block">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block-3 block">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block-4 block">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then change the LIs to something like this:

```
<li><a href="" onClick='$(".block").hide();$(".block-1").show()'>Nav 1</a></li>
<li><a href="" onClick='$(".block").hide();$(".block-2").show()'>Nav 2</a></li>
<li><a href="" onClick='$(".block").hide();$(".block-3").show()'>Nav 3</a></li>
<li><a href="" onClick='$(".block").hide();$(".block-4").show()'>Nav 4</a></li>
```

This will first hide all content blocks, then show the one you want to be shown.

Comment: Thanks for this, hiding the content div *IS* necessary, vital, actually. I see why it's confusing, but the design is such that the container cannot be showing until content inside does also.

Comment: Well, then the code gets a little more complicated, but it is still doable. Just throw in a `$(".content").show();` before hiding the standard blocks :)

Answer (score 0):

first modify your html a bit.

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#block-1">Nav 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#block-2">Nav 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#block-3">Nav 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#block-4">Nav 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
  <div id="block-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="block-2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="block-3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="block-4">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

next, don't hide the content div. Then you can do this.

```
$('#nav li a').click(function() {
    $('.content div').hide();
    var block = $(this).attr('href');
    $(block).show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To be a little more flexible (so you don't have to match indexes and so forth) I recommend something like this.

## html:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href=".block-1">Nav 1</a></li>
  <li><a href=".block-2">Nav 2</a></li>
  <li><a href=".block-3">Nav 3</a></li>
  <li><a href=".block-4">Nav 4</a></li>
 </ul>
<div id="content">
  <div class="block-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block-3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block-4">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav > li > a').click(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var elementToShow = $(this).attr('href');
        $(elementToShow).slideDown().parent().slideDown().find(' > :not('+elementToShow+')').slideUp();
    });
});
```

This will also work with the content element hidden.

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXpws/4/)